# Easy way to fill in an Excel file with Python

Tags: python, linux, macos, excel

Let us say I have an excel file called **test.xlsx**, which is a workbook with three sheets, where sheet1 is called **hello1**, sheet2 two is called **hello2**, and sheet3 is called **bye**.

Now, I'd like to read the file, and then re-write the same file but ONLY change the values in (column B, row 11) of the sheet named hello2, and (column D, row 14) of sheet named bye.  The values I want to give there are 'test' (a string), and 135, respectively (i.e., write test in sheet hello2 and 14 in sheet bye).

You may be wondering why I am asking such odd question but basically I am looking to gain some of the following skills/knowledge:

- To be able to read a workbook and then a specific sheet of an excel file using python
- To be able to write to an excel sheet at a given position using python

Note: for reference, I can use any version of python in redhat server, the excel file was generated with my mac, saved as xlsx format using excel for mac 2011. version 14.0.1, and then I copied the excel file to redhat server.

Comment: If it was saved as Excel 97 - why is it `test.xlsx`? It'd be useful if you could state for certain what version it is (and what version of Excel you'd like the output in)

Comment: @Jon Clements sorry you are right, was saved as xlsx using excel for mac 2011, version 14.0.1 - just updated the Q

Comment: Have you taken a look at the xlwt, xlrd, and xlutils modules for Python? (http://www.python-excel.org)

Comment: @josh, great suggestion, looking into it now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `xlwt`, `xlrd`, and `xlutils` modules (which you can find here: [python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org)).

With `xlrd`, `xlwt` and `xlutils`, you use `xlrd` to read a workbook, and then you use `xlutils` to make a writeable copy. Since what you're doing isn't dependent on the values already in the cells, you won't need to use `xlrd` at all except for opening the book.

A quick mockup of your code would look like:

```
import xlrd, xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

read_book = xlrd.open_workbook("Path/To/Doc", formatting_info=True) #Make Readable Copy
write_book = copy(read_book) #Make Writeable Copy

write_sheet1 = write_book.get_sheet(1) #Get sheet 1 in writeable copy
write_sheet1.write(1, 11, 'test') #Write 'test' to cell (B, 11)

write_sheet2 = write_book.get_sheet(2) #Get sheet 2 in writeable copy
write_sheet2.write(3, 14, '135') #Write '135' to cell (D, 14)

write_book.save("New/File/Path") #Save the newly written copy. Enter the same as the old path to write over
```

Comment: Are all the excel formulas in the original copy still preserved in the new copy?

Comment: xlrt / xlwt are considered legacy (https://groups.google.com/g/python-excel/c/P6TjJgFVjMI/m/g8d0eWxTBQAJ), as can only read and write XLS files, the old Excel format (pre-2003). For reading and writing XLSX files: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl

Comment: @Jose if you make a new answer to this question using openpyxl, and pointing out xlrt/xlwt are deprecated, you’d have my upvote :)